# How to change the default language feature for sitecore multilingual solution

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

As per the default addressing for a Sitecore multilingual solution, is there a way to change the default addressing, for example

www.mydomain.com/zh/products for a simplified Chinese to www.mydomain.com/sc/products

without altering the sitecore pipeline. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without altering Sitecore pipelines or LinkManagers, the only obvious way I can think of achieving this would be to use the [IIS Url Rewrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh943097%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) module. You could set up configuration in that, to rewrite some or all of your URLs.

What isn't clear from your question is; if you want to force ALL URLs onto the /sc/ path, or you want to get rid of language embedding in the url unconditionally?   If the latter, you can modify your UrlOptions to disable "languageEmbedding" by setting it to "never".

Comment: Let consider say we want to have the following mappings 
alias="sc" culture="zh-cn"
alias="sc" culture="zh-CN"
alias="jp" culture="ja-jp"
alias="jp" culture="ja-JP"

so each url will use the alias as per every language. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may [register](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Custom_Language_Registration.aspx) `sc` language based on the template of `zh` one on your machine. Then you can rename `zh` language item definition in Sitecore. 
It may work but there could be unknown repercussions as a result. Anyways if you decide to try it out, backup your databases before you start renaming those languages. If it does work and you give it a go, document it for those who'll take over solution after you. They'll be quite thankful for that :).